# Creating a new collection throwing error

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Below is the error getting while creating a new collection using mongoose.

```
  D:\Workspace\node-2012-20\node\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:191
      throw new Error('Schema hasn\'t been registered for model "' + name + '"
            ^
Error: Schema hasn't been registered for model "testDocAccessModel".
Use mongoose.model(name, schema)
    at Mongoose.model (D:\Workspace\node-2012-20\node\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:191)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

Below is the code

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    exports.TestDocumentAccessSchema = new Schema({
      Id: { type: Schema.ObjectId },
      parentId: { type: Schema.ObjectId },
      userId: { type : String },
      userName: { type : String },
    });

    var testDocAccessModel = mongoose.model('TestDocumentAccess', exports.TestDocumentAccessSchema);
```

Any clues ?

Comment: Maybe check your require order to make sure you are requiring the model before using it in your controller?

Comment: The error message references model `"testDocAccessModel"`, are you sure you're looking at the right code?

Comment: Tested your code: works fine, I think @JamesOR is right...check your require order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your code like this and let me know was it helpful

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    var TestDocumentAccessSchema = new Schema({
      Id: { type: Schema.ObjectId },
      parentId: { type: Schema.ObjectId },
      userId: { type : String },
      userName: { type : String },
    });

    var testDocAccessModel = mongoose.model('TestDocumentAccess',TestDocumentAccessSchema); 
    exports.TestDocumentAccessSchema = TestDocumentAccessSchema;
```